# Access the notification center in IOS from Phonegap

Tags: ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to access the nofification center using phonegap . I am developing iPad app using phonegap (Cordova - 1.9.0 ) and JQM 1.0.1.

Is there any way to access the notification centre using phonegap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application will have to send a push notification. Which the user will have to agree to receive.

Either a location notification using the following plugin :
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/LocalNotifications

Or Push Notification via Apples Server or Urban Airship Push 
http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/06/09/phonegap-push/

Once you have a push setup the user can select your app from notification center in Settings.

Comment: thank you.. I have found DrewDahlman solution and  solved my problem. thank you very much